# Query list of lists

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose we have classes:

```
Class School
{
    List<Student> Students;
}

Class Student
{
    List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers;
}
```

How to write a query to get list of all PhoneNumbers in a School?

Comment: Have a look at `SelectMany`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx) like:

```
List<PhoneNumber> allPhoneNumbers = school.Students
                                          .SelectMany(r => r.PhoneNumbers)
                                          .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple LINQ solution would be to use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
School.Students.SelectMany(s => s.PhoneNumbers);
```